# How to insert value into Java Object

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Java Object in which I want to insert value. For example I want to do this:

```
private UserData ud = new UserData();

public class UserData
{
    private String hostName;
    private String userName;
    private String passwd;

    public UserData(String hostName, String userName, String passwd)
    {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    private UserData()
    {
    }

    public String getHostName()
    {
        return hostName;
    }

    public void setHostName(String hostName)
    {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPasswd()
    {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd)
    {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }
}
```

And I have this simple text fields

```
TextField textFieldsz = new TextField();
grid.add(textFieldsz, 1, 0);

Text chartTitle = new Text("User name:");
grid.add(chartTitle, 0, 1);

TextField textFieldds = new TextField();
grid.add(textFieldds, 1, 1);

Text chartcTisstle = new Text("Password:");
grid.add(chartcTisstle, 0, 2);

PasswordField textFieeds = new PasswordField();
grid.add(textFieeds, 1, 2);
```

And I have this button which will be used for login

```
btnLogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }
});
```

I have a basic knowledge how to make the businesses logic. Can you tell me in JavaFX how I can insert the values from the TextFields into the Java Object and perform some action?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to solve your problem.

```
final UserData ud = new UserData();     
GridPane grid = new GridPane();     
final TextField textFieldsz = new TextField();
grid.add(textFieldsz, 1, 0);
Text chartTitle = new Text("User name:");
grid.add(chartTitle, 0, 1);
final TextField textFieldds = new TextField();
grid.add(textFieldds, 1, 1);
Text chartcTisstle = new Text("Password:");
grid.add(chartcTisstle, 0, 2);
final PasswordField textFieeds = new PasswordField();
grid.add(textFieeds, 1, 2)      
Scene sc = new Scene(grid,400,400);     
Button btn = new Button("PRESS");       
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        ud.setHostName(textFieldsz.getText());
        ud.setUserName(textFieldds.getText());
        ud.setPasswd(textFieeds.getText());
        arg0.consume();

    }
});
```

As you can see, you must add the `final` keyword to the objects that you use in your inner anonymous class (the eventhandler of the button).

Another way is by using [JavaFX-Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm), but I don't think that binding is suitable for a login screen.